# Finding a formula for matrix norms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I am asked to find a formula for computing $||A||_{1,2}$ defined as $max_{x\neq 0}\frac{||Ax||_2}{||x||_1}$ ,where $||.||_p$ is the general p norm on the vector.

---

I know that $||A||_2$ = $max_{i=1:n}\sqrt{(λ_i(A^TA))}$
where $λ_i(A^TA)$ is the i
th eigenvalue of $A^TA$ and  $||x||_2 \leq ||x||_1 \leq \sqrt{n}||x||_2$

---

what I have tried :

$||A||_{1,2}$ = $max_{x\neq 0}\frac{||Ax||_2}{||x||_1}$
$\leq max_{x\neq 0}\frac{||Ax||_2}{||x||_2}$= $max_{i=1:n}\sqrt{(λ_i(A^TA))}$

and I cannot argue any further.

I am trying to find a formula just like I found for $||A||_2$

Comment: Have you considered trying with $A = I$, $A$ diagonal, ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_i$ be the $i$-th column of $A$ and $x_i$ the $i$-th component of $x.$ Then
$$
\|Ax\|_2
=   \left\| \sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i \right\|_2
\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \left\|  a_i x_i \right\|_2 \\
= \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i| \;\|a_i\|_2 
\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \left(|x_i| \, \max_j \|a_j\|_2 \right) \\
=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|\right)\left(\max_j \|a_j\|_2\right)
= \|x\|_1 \,\max_j \|a_j\|_2
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac {\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_1}
\leq \max_j \|a_j\|_2
$$
It can easily be seen that equality is obtained if $x = e_i,$ where $e_i$ is the $i$-th element of the standard basis and $i$ is chosen such that $\|a_i\|_2 = \max_j \|a_j\|_2.$ Therefore
$$
\|A\|_{1,2} = \max_j \|a_j\|_2 = \sqrt{\max\operatorname{diag}(A^TA)}
$$